# Calculate factorials with threads in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, factorial

I have to test if n = 17 is a prime number: (n-1)! mod n = n-1. For that first I have to calculate the factorial of 16 through 4 threads, that means that the interval 1..16 has to be divided in 4 sub-intervals: 1..4, 5..8, 9..12, 14..16. I have managed to test if 17 is a prime number through 16 threads, one for each operation, but I don’t know how I could sub-divide it so that the operations are done in only 4 threads.

I would very much appreciate some ideas, thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import threading

n = 17
t = n-1
ts = []
num = (n-1)/t
       
def calcFak():
    for i in range(t):
        c = i*(n-1)/t+1
        thread = threading.Thread(target=threads, args = (c,))
        ts.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        thread.join()
        

def threads(var):
    print(f"start thread {var}")
    global num
    num = num * var
    print(f"end thread {var}")

def managerThread(thread):
    calcFak()
    print(num)
    if num % n == t:
         print(n, ' is Prime')
    else:
         print(n, ' is not Prime')
    
    
t2 = threading.Thread(target = managerThread, args=(ts,))
t2.start()
```

Comment: is it important that the subintervales are each in an own thread? I feel like having 16 tasks anad let them be performed by 4 threads would be more efficient.

Comment: Hi Finn, thank you for your reply. In this case each subinterval has to have an own thread. It is an exercise to practice synchronization in Python, so I am not really sure if it is expected to be efficient

Comment: You should not expect to be able to do parallel computations in pure Python code: https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to implement this particular algorithm? There are ways to test whether N is prime without explicitly calculating (N-1)!

Comment: Hi Solomon, thank you for your answer. This is an exercise to practice synchronisation with Python, and I am following the instructions provided, one of them being the way n is tested to be prime or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are calculating everything sequentially because of the thread `join()` statement in your `calcFak()` function. Thus, the execution of your function right now is actually the same as the code below:

```
n = 17
t = n - 1
num = t/t

for i in range(t):
    c = i*t/t + 1
    print(f'Start {c}')
    num = num * c
    print(f'End thread {c}')

print(num)
if num % n == t:
    print(f'{n} is a prime number')
else:
    print(f'{n} is not a prime number')
```

As you can see, no threading benefit. Instead, use [queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) and worker functions to subdivide your program's execution:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import time
n = 17
t = n - 1
num = t/t

# For threading
q = Queue()
num_lock = threading.Lock() # Lock so that no threads can overwrite our num value
threads = []                # List to store created threads

# Our worker gets items from the queue and processes them
def worker():
    global num
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            c = q.get()
            num_lock.acquire()
            num = num * c
            num_lock.release()
            q.task_done()

for i in range(t):
    q.put(i*t/t + 1)

for thread in range(4):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=worker))
    threads[-1].daemon = True
    threads[-1].start()
    print('Made 1 thread')

q.join()

if num % n == t:
    print(f'{n} is a prime number')
else:
    print(f'{n} is not a prime number')

# Prints:
# Made 1 thread
# Made 1 thread
# Made 1 thread
# Made 1 thread
# 17 is a prime number
```

In the code above, we create a queue that holds data for the worker functions to use. The worker functions get a lock on the `num` variable, and then modify it. Once the queue is empty (which happens after we join the queue with `q.join()`) we then access the final value of the `num` variable to determine if the number is prime or not.